# Загрузка объявления.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в коде. У меня два файла, один -форма, второй обработчик. Мне нужно, чтобы в базу заносились объявления с фотографиями. Если, пишу `if (isset($_POST['foto'])) {$foto = $_FILES['foto']; }` - денвер пишет - неопределенная переменная фото на линии 17. А если вместо   FILES  пишу  POST  -    `if (isset($_POST['foto'])) {$foto = $_POST['foto']; }` - вместо имени добавляется ноль. Сам файл в нужную директорию не загружается. Код вообще игнорируется. Если напишете код, напишите, пожалуйста, с пояснениями, я пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в php. И еще вопрос:  несовсем понятно значение  `"image/" вот в этой строчке  $name = md5(microtime()).".".substr($type, strlen("image/"));  - это папка?`

Вот код:

```
Форма:

<? include ("blocks/bd.php");
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM obyavleniya");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

<title><? $myrow['title']; ?></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<meta name="keywords" content="ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ">
<meta name="description" content="ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ">

</head>

<body>

<div id='levcol'>
<h3 align='center'>Добавление объявления</h3>

<form name='forma1' method='post' action='editobyav.php' entype='multipart form-data'>

 <p align='left'>
 <label>Ваше имя/название организации<br>
 <input value="" type="text" name="title" id="title" size="35" maxlength="100">
 </label>
 </p>
 <p align='left'>
 <label>Краткое описание объявления<br>
  <textarea name="meta_d" id="meta_d" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
 </label>
 </p>
 <p align='left'>
 <label>Ключевые слова для объявления<br>
 <input value="" type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k" size="47" maxlength="255">
 </label>
 </p>

 <p align='left'>
 <label>Дата добавления<br>
 <input value="<?php $date = date("Y-m-d"); echo $date; ?>" type="text" name="date" id="date" size="30" >
 </label>
 </p>

 <p align='left'>
 <label>Полное описание услуг<br>
 <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50px" rows="20px"></textarea>
 </label>
 </p>

 <p align='left'>
 <label>Город<br>
 <input value="" type="text" name="gorod" id="gorod">
 </label>
 </p>

 <p align='left'>
 <label>Фото (необязательно)<br>
 <input value="" type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
 </label>
 </p>

 <p align='left'></p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Добавить">
 </label>
 </p>
 </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Обработчик:

<?php 
include ("blocks/bd.php");

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {$title = $_POST['title']; if ($title == '') {unset($title);}}

if (isset($_POST['meta_d'])) {$meta_d = $_POST['meta_d']; if ($meta_d == '') {unset($meta_d);}}

if (isset($_POST['meta_k'])) {$meta_k = $_POST['meta_k']; if ($meta_k == '') {unset($meta_k);}}

if (isset($_POST['date'])) {$data = $_POST['date']; if ($date == '') {unset($date);}}

if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}

if (isset($_POST['gorod'])) {$gorod = $_POST['gorod']; if ($gorod == '') {unset($gorod);}}

if (isset($_POST['editobyav'])) {$foto = $_FILES['foto'];

function isSecurity($foto){
$name = $foto['name'];
$type = $foto['type'];
$size = $foto['size'];

$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4"); 
foreach ($blacklist as $item) {if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $name))return false;}

if (($type != "image/gif") && ($type != "image/png") && ($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg"))return false;

if ($size > 800 * 1024) return false;

}

function LoadFoto($foto){
$type = $foto['type'];
$uploaddir = "avatars/";
$name = md5(microtime()).".".substr($type, strlen("image/"));
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$name;
if(move_uploaded_file($fofo["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) 
{
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO obyavleniya (foto) VALUES ('$name')"); 
}
else return false;
}

if (isSecurity($foto)) LoadFoto($foto);
else $message = "Ошибка при загрузке фото";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
if (isset($title) && isset($meta_d) && isset($meta_k) && isset($date) && isset($text) && isset($gorod))
{

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO obyavleniya (title,meta_d,meta_k,date,text,gorod) VALUES ('$title', '$meta_d', '$meta_k', '$date', '$text', '$gorod')");

if ($result == 'true') {echo "<p>Ваше объявление успешно добавлено!</p>";}
else {echo "<p>Ваше объявление не добавлено!</p>";}

} 
else

{
echo "<p>Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому объявление не может быть добавлено.</p>";
}

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уроки Попова можно использовать, как руководство "*Как делать не надо*" или "*Ошибки практически на каждой строке*". Если вы скачали эти уроки бесплатно, то удалить немедленно, а если купили диск, то подарить коллеге-врагу, тогда он никогда не будет вам конкурентом.

Comment: ))))))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код ужасен, поэтому особо не смотрел, но даже при беглом осмотре видно две ошибки, уверен если покопаться, найдется еще.

1) **entype='multipart form-data'** Неправильно, надо писать **entype='multipart/form-data'**

2) **$fofo["tmp_name"]** у вас нет такой переменной, явно опечатка, должно быть **$foto["tmp_name"]**

Ну и пример, первая ссылка в [гугле](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&gs_nf=1&tok=lElwrd0QqMPR_4zE3t4dQA&cp=8&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=php+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&pf=p&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80) http://www.softtime.ru/scripts/upload.php

Comment: На будущее вместо <?php $date = date("Y-m-d"); echo $date; ?> 
пишите более кратко: <?=date("Y-m-d")?>

Доктайп то же старенький, пишите короче

Comment: Благодарю!